# Can someone explain exactly what Bates is doing on page 42 of Fundamentals of Astrodynamics?

Tags: astrophysics

(See below for answer, I made a few math errors and a bad assumption about what he did)

Or rather, can someone explain exactly why he's using $v=1 \frac {DU} {TU}$ when according to the first given is $v = 2.593625\times10^4 \frac{ft}{s}$ ($7905.37 \frac{m}{s}$ or $0.999342 \frac{DU}{TU}$). Also given is the altitude ($1.046284\times10^7 ft$) (distance to focus: $r=3.1388\times10^7ft$ or $1.5 DU$)

The first portion of this asks for $\mathcal{E} = \frac {v^2}{2} - \frac{\mu}{r}$, but using the canonical units. Pretty straightforward.

He doesn't show his intermediate step here, but given that he gets $\mathcal{E}=-0.167 \frac{DU^2}{TU^2}$, he's clearly plugging in $v = 1 \frac{DU}{TU}$ into this equation. (This isn't quite correct, see comment below)

What I don't understand is *why* he's doing this. If I plug in his numbers without converting to DU and TU, I get a completely different answer than he does (I get $-1.12702 \times 10^8 \frac{ft^2}{s^2}$ to his $-1.12339 \times 10^8 \frac{ft^2}{s^2}$). If I convert to $r = 1.5DU$ and $v = 0.999342 \frac{DU}{TU}$, I get a pretty similar answer to the one I got using the units directly, $-1.67324 \frac{DU^2}{TU^2}$ or $-1.12706 \times 10^8 \frac{ft^2}{s^2}$

So I'm trying to figure out:

- Why he's using v = 1 DU/TU here,
- Did I (against 50 years of odds) find a mistake in his work? Or a misprint? That seems unlikely.

Assumptions:

- $DU = 2.09252 \times 10^7 ft$ (one earth radius)
- $TU = 806.263s$ (determined from $TU^2 = \frac{DU^3}{\mu}$)

Comment: I definitely seem to have been the one making the error. In determining $\mu$ for some reason I used $5.98\times10^{25}kg$ instead of $\times10^{24}kg$. It was a silly error that I could have solved by checking.

I also noticed after correcting this that v is not quite $1 \frac{DU}{TU}$, but rather $v = 0.999342\frac{DU}{TU}$, close enough to be 1. However it would have been helpful for him to have noted that rather than quietly rounding it to 1.

My result is closer to his, but still not the same.

Comment: I have corrected several numbers in my original post, so you may need to look at the history to see the incorrect ones.

Comment: Using medieval units may leed to crashes. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter.

Comment: Yeah, I like to give my students that example too. In my case, it was a magnitude error moreso than a unit error (I was letting my TI89 handle unit conversions internally).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I made a few mistakes that threw my answer.

- I used $5.98\times 10^{25}kg$ instead of $5.98\times 10^{24}kg$ when calculating $\mu$ and TU. That really threw the numbers.
- I assumed he used $v=1 \frac{DU}{TU}$ based on his result. He didn't, but he skipped an intermediate step that might have tipped me off that this was him rounding rather than using 1 for some other reason. Once I determined the correct TU, it became somewhat more apparent that $v = 0.999342 \frac{DU}{TU} \approx 1 \frac{DU}{TU}$ was what he was doing.
- Having the correct DU and TU allowed for the correct conversion back from canonical units to US customary.